# How to create a new data frame based on conditions from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Just getting into Python, so hopefully I'm not asking a stupid question here...

So I have a pandas dataframe named "df_complete' with let's say 100 rows, and containing columns named: "type", "writer", "status", 'col a', 'col c'. I want to create/update a new dataframe named "temp_df" and create it based on conditions using "df_complete" values.

```
temp_df = pandas.DataFrame()

if ((df_complete['type'] == 'NDD') & (df_complete['writer'] == 'Mary') & (df_complete['status'] != '7')):
    temp_df['col A'] = df_complete['col a']
    temp_df['col B'] = 'good'
    temp_df['col C'] = df_complete['col c']
```

However, when I do this, I got the following error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I read this thread and changed my "and" to "&":
[Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

I also read this thread here to put everything in parenthesis: [comparing dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool] in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531416/comparing-dtyped-float64-array-with-a-scalar-of-type-bool-in-pandas-datafram)

But the error is still present. What is causing this? and how can I fix it?

** follow up question **
Also, how can I obtain the index values of those rows that met the condition?

Comment: The problem is you are putting your big boolean expression, which results in a boolean-valued Series, in an `if` condition, which, as the error says, has a truth value that is ambiguous. Can you say in words exactly what that `if` block is suppose to accomplish?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting only columns `col a` and `col c`:

```
temp_df = df_complete.loc[(df_complete['type'] == 'NDD') & 
                         (df_complete['writer'] == 'Mary') & 
                         (df_complete['status'] != '7'), ['col a','col c']]
#rename columns
temp_df = temp_df.rename(columns={'col a':'col A','col c':'col C'})
#add new column 
temp_df['col B'] = 'good'
#reorder columns
temp_df = temp_df[['col A','col B','col C']]
```

Sample:

```
df_complete = pd.DataFrame({'type':  ['NDD','NDD','NT'],
                            'writer':['Mary','Mary','John'],
                            'status':['4','5','6'],
                            'col a': [1,3,5],
                            'col b': [5,3,6],
                            'col c': [7,4,3]}, index=[3,4,5])

print (df_complete)
   col a  col b  col c status type writer
3      1      5      7      4  NDD   Mary
4      3      3      4      5  NDD   Mary
5      5      6      3      6   NT   John

temp_df = df_complete.loc[(df_complete['type'] == 'NDD') & 
                         (df_complete['writer'] == 'Mary') & 
                         (df_complete['status'] != '7'), ['col a','col c']]

print (temp_df)  
   col a  col c
3      1      7
4      3      4

temp_df = temp_df.rename(columns={'col a':'col A','col c':'col C'})
#add new column 
temp_df['col B'] = 'good'
#reorder columns
temp_df = temp_df[['col A','col B','col C']]
print (temp_df)  
   col A col B  col C
3      1  good      7
4      3  good      4
```

Comment: what is `df` here? `df_complete`, perhaps?

Comment: Hi @jezrael thank you SO much for the detailed explanation! Can I ask a follow up question as to how to obtain the index values of those rows that met the condition?

Comment: I think it is not necessary, because if use `boolean indexing` it select data from original dataframe with original indexes.

Comment: I edit sample with custom indexes and with returning 2 rows - there indexes from original dataframe. then if need select them use `temp_df.index`

Comment: @jezrael Thank you so much! Your answer is truly helpful

Comment: ix is depreciated for those look at this years later

Comment: `ix` is deprecated, use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead.

Comment: May I ask how you'd do if you've just one column to check, but against a list of possible values? How do you loop through the list instead of writing explicitly all the `or`? Thanks!

Comment: @DavideBarranca - You can use [`isin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql)

Answer (score 3):

In the current version of Pandas, the `.ix` has deprecated; instead, use `.loc`.

```
temp_df = df_complete.loc[]
```